# Functional Programming/Streams Exercise

Tags: java, collections, java-8, functional-programming, java-stream

> Write a method named davidist which returns an `Optional<Float>`
>   result and has 3 parameters:
>
> - a Stream s (Float type)
> - a Predicate p for Float type elements
> - a binary operator for Float type elements
>
> Method chooses from the stream the elements for which p is true and
>   returns: if there are more than one elements, the result of the binary
>   operator applied between the elements for which p is true (i.e a1 c a2
>   c a3 c a4 c), otherwise it returns Optional.empty().

This is what I've done so far, can somebody help me out?

```
public Optional<Float> davidist(Stream<Float> s, Predicate<Float> p, byte b) {
    if () {

    } else {
        return Optional.empty();
    }
}
```

Comment: Since the current answer doesn't explain much. Relate *binary operator for Float type elements* => `BinaryOperator<Float> binaryOp`. No from the stream you need to filter elements for which the predicate holds true using `stream.filter(predicate)` and finally reduce such elements when found in multiple occurrence using the operation with `stream.filter(predicate).reduce(binaryOp).`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following method is the one you are looking for:

```java
public Optional<Float> davidist(
        Stream<Float> stream, Predicate<Float> tester, BinaryOperator<Float> op) {

    return stream           // Elements stream
            .filter(tester) // Stream of elements that passed 'tester' test
            .reduce(op);    // Optional<Float> resulting by reducing elements using 'op'
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: An explanation would definitely be helpful with such an answer.

Comment: This doesn't return empty if there's 1 element.